direct io - How to write an odd-sized file using O_DIRECT on Linux
I am experimenting with ways with which I can write odd-sized files i.e., file size not a multiple of block size(512 bytes) using O_DIRECT. Below are two code snippets, one which uses syscalls(open,read,write) and other uses libc calls(fopen,fread,fwrite). Both follow the same logic: write full sized blocks -> switch O_DIRECT off -> write tail end -> switch O_DIRECT on.
test_sys.c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512

int main()
{
    size_t buf_size = 1024 * 1024;
    char *buf = aligned_alloc(BLOCK_SIZE, buf_size);
    int bytes_read = 0;
    int total_bytes_read = 0;
    int bytes_written = 0;
    int total_bytes_written = 0;

    int in_fd = open("./data", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | __O_DIRECT, 0600);
    int out_fd = open("./data.out", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | __O_DIRECT, 0600);

    while ((bytes_read = read(in_fd, buf, buf_size)) > 0)
    {
        total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
        int tmp;
        if (bytes_read % BLOCK_SIZE != 0)
        {
            int flags = fcntl(out_fd, F_GETFL);
            if (fcntl(out_fd, F_SETFL, flags & ~__O_DIRECT))
                printf("failed to disable O_DIRECT\n");

            bytes_written = write(out_fd, buf, bytes_read);

            if (fcntl(out_fd, F_SETFL, flags))
                printf("failed to re-enable O_DIRECT\n");
        }
        else
        {
            bytes_written = write(out_fd, buf, bytes_read);
        }
        total_bytes_written += bytes_written;
    }

    printf("read: %d bytes in total\n", total_bytes_read);
    printf("write: %d bytes in total\n", total_bytes_written);

    free(buf);
    close(in_fd);
    close(out_fd);

    return 0;
}

test_lib.c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512

int main()
{
    size_t buf_size = 1024 * 1024;
    char *buf = aligned_alloc(BLOCK_SIZE, buf_size);
    int bytes_read = 0;
    int total_bytes_read = 0;
    int bytes_written = 0;
    int total_bytes_written = 0;

    int in_fd = open("./data", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | __O_DIRECT, 0600);
    FILE *in_file = fdopen(in_fd, "rb");
    int out_fd = open("./data.out", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | __O_DIRECT, 0600);
    FILE *out_file = fdopen(out_fd, "wb");

    while ((bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, buf_size, in_file)) > 0)
    {
        total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
        if (bytes_read % BLOCK_SIZE != 0)
        {
            int flags = fcntl(out_fd, F_GETFL);
            if (fcntl(out_fd, F_SETFL, flags & ~__O_DIRECT))
                printf("failed to disable O_DIRECT\n");

            bytes_written = fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, out_file);

            if (fcntl(out_fd, F_SETFL, flags))
                printf("failed to re-enable O_DIRECT\n");
        }
        else
        {
            bytes_written = fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, out_file);
        }
        total_bytes_written += bytes_written;
    }

    printf("read: %d bytes in total\n", total_bytes_read);
    printf("write: %d bytes in total\n", total_bytes_written);

    free(buf);
    fclose(in_file);
    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}

For both the cases, the output is the same:
read: 1050625 bytes in total
write: 1050625 bytes in total

But, in case of test_lib.c the file is only of 1048576 bytes. Can someone help me understand why? How can I get the correct results using libc calls?
I expected the same results in both cases.

It seems more straightforward to write all full blocks with __O_DIRECT and then truncate the file.

There are issues with [artificially] using O_DIRECT on a FILE *. IIRC, O_DIRECT requires that the buffer pointer passed to read/write is page aligned. fread/fwrite don't know anything about that requirement, so there are issues. Use mmap on the file instead. See my answer: read line by line in the most efficient way platform specific

@CraigEstey My future goal is to implement an i/o interface using O_DIRECT in a database-related project. The reason I thought of using O_DIRECT was to bypass the kernel cache, which will improve performance and reduce cpu overhead. Will mmap be useful in this case? Or do you have any other suggestions?

mmap will do much better than O_DIRECT, fread/fwrite, or read/write. Details/benchmarks in my link.

Just to be clear. O_DIRECT does not "bypass" the kernel buffers. It tells the kernel to use the userspace buffers as the kernel buffers. mmap will map the kernel buffers directly into userspace memory. Better and more flexible (e.g. madvise to force quick flushing or prefetch). You might also want to look at [the relatively new] io_uring.

It's maybe good to think of O_DIRECT as the disk-cache equivalent of a non-temporal load or store instruction: you're telling the kernel that you want to transfer data to or from disk but you do not want that data to be cached in case of future accesses to the same file. This is almost never what you actually want.

@CraigEstey O_DIRECT requires that the buffer pointer passed to read/write is page aligned.  That's a Linux requirement driven by nothing but the limitations of the Linux kernel - it's not a hardware limit.  I was delivering high-performance IO solutions 20 years ago that were able to sustain multiple GB/sec performance that pretty much relied upon direct IO for performance.  Without direct IO we took a 30-40% performance hit.  IME mmap() is the worst-by-far way to stream data fast - you do not want to pay the price of creating many, many mappings only to throw each one away

(cont)  But, unless you have control over the entire data flow - disk media to application memory and can tune things like buffer size, memory location on non-NUMA systems, data layout on disk, file system block size, location on disk where the filesystem stores data - i.e. everything, you can probably get 90%+ max performance a system of the normal thrown-together-with-zero-performance-tuning-thought disks/disk controllers/file systems/file system parameters/OS options just by using a big enough FILE * buffer.

(cont) So unless you're designing the entire hardware/software stack for the best possible performance - and actually doing significant performance testing along the way - the effort is usually not worth it.  The other thing direct IO gives an application is much better control of when data is actually sync'd to disk.  Which is why databases tend to use it.

@AndrewHenle Please do check out my linked answer (inc the pastebin link in the comments). It has benchmarks that prove what I was saying. What multiple mappings? You create one [and leave it].

@CraigEstey I did.  You benchmarked the read of lines of text, with nary a mention of direct IO.  And, a single call to mmap() will result in a mapping of every page.  Each and every one of those requires updates to page tables and TLBs - meaning single threaded contention over common resources - and likely TLB flushes.  mmap() is probably the slowest way to stream data when each byte of data is only accessed once.

@AndrewHenle A single mmap will not result in the mapping of every page. It only maps pages on demand. It marks the region in the process but doesn't necessary assign page slots (or pages in the file) or mappings in the page table or page directories (similar to ftruncate creating holes at first). As to TLBs, except for explicit ptlb insts, the H/W does the flush/load of the TLB entries. With madvise, mmap is faster because with read/write you can't force the system to release the cached page slots that you no longer need (but can with madvise)

Never ever write a file with mmap. Firstly writing past the end of the file is UB so you have to fallocate the file first. Next writing the first byte of each page will page fault and read in the page from the filesystem and then restart writing the byte. So write now reads the file first. Last any errors with mmap will give you segfaults, if they are noticed at all.

O_DIRECT has many pitfalls and problems and weather you gain any speed with it is dubious. When writing files to filesystems it's questionable if O_DIRECT does anything or isn't way worse. Modern filesystems will perform a lot better if they know how much data you will write and can collect many small writes into one big one. I would suggest looking at liburing for high performance IO under linux.

@CraigEstey A single mmap will not result in the mapping of every page. It only maps pages on demand. Which is exactly why mmap() throughput can be abysmal.   Nothing like having to pause and wait for a page to get swapped in and populated from disk exactly when you need to perform.  mmap is faster...  No, it's not.  Creating mappings when they're only used once and then thrown away can not be faster than not spending the time creating those mappings.  And try it on a system with a lot of memory contention...
